# Matlab: How to compute the inverse of a matrix

Tags: matlab, math, inverse

I want to find the T inverse as given in the picture. The first picture is the matrix T and the other is T inverse.

[image: T]

[image: T inverse]

```
I = eye(3);
T = [I/2, (j/2)*I, 0;
     I/2,  (-j/2)*I, 0;
     0,0,I];
```

Error using horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

Then I tried with `I = eye(2)` and got the same error. What is the proper way?

Comment: what's wrong with `inv` - the result when you google matlab+matrix+inverse? Just make sure you denote the imaginay unit as `1i` or `1j`.

Comment: @thewaywewalk I think the main problem is that the OP is using the literal `0` while the written equations are using a matrix **0**; hence, the dimension error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given

```
I = eye(3);
```

you want to multiply [**element-wise** using `.*`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html) with `A` (make sure you use the imaginary unit **`1j`** and not an undefined variable `j`)

```
A = [1/2, (1j/2), 0;
     1/2,  (-1j/2), 0;
     0,0,1];
```

to get `T`

```
T = A.*I
```

But apart from that it feels like you actually want to multiply `A` with a constant `C = I = 1`

```
T = A.*1
```

The inverse you obtain with the [**`inv`erse**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inv.html) function:

```
Tinv = inv(T)
```

Comment: Tinv =

   2.0000,                  0,                  0     ;     
        0,                  0 + 2.0000i  ,      0  ;        
        0    ,              0      ,       1.0000;

Comment: I am getting a different value for the element at row 2, first column which in the picture is  -jI but in the output of the code the element is 0. Another thing I noticed that in the picture for `Tinv`, ther is no `2`, but Matlab has multiplied the elements with `2`. Can you please check and let me know if you are getting the same result for `Tinv` as mine?

Comment: @SKM the code in this answer gives the correct answer, matching the one given in your question. `A = [1/2, (1j/2), 0; 1/2,  (-1j/2), 0; 0,0,1];` Then `inv(A) = [1, 1, 0; -i, i, 0; 0, 0, 1];` as stated above. Try clearing your workspace (using `clear`) and starting again.

Comment: @Wolfie: thank you for checking the result for me. I cleared the workspsce and got the correct answer.

Comment: @thewaywewalk: thank you for your answer. Can you please let me know what command to use for the operation T^H where H is the Hermitian operator for complex numbers?