# Multiplication of matrices involving inverse operation: getting infinity

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, inverse

In my earlier question asked here : [Matlab: How to compute the inverse of a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43177790/matlab-how-to-compute-the-inverse-of-a-matrix)

I wanted to know how to perform inverse operation

```
A = [1/2, (1j/2), 0;
     1/2, (-1j/2), 0;
     0,0,1]

 T = A.*1

 Tinv = inv(T)
```

The output is `Tinv` =

```
   1.0000             1.0000                  0          
        0 - 1.0000i        0 + 1.0000i        0          
        0                  0             1.0000
```

which is the same as in the second picture. The first picture is the matrix `A`

[image: T]

[image: T inverse]

However for a larger matrix say 5 by 5, if I don't use the identity, `I` to perform element wise multiplication, I am getting infinity value. Here is an example

```
A = [1/2, (1j/2),  1/2, (1j/2),  0;
     1/2, (-1j/2), 1/2, (-1j/2), 0;
     1/2, (1j/2),  1/2, (1j/2),  0;
     1/2, (-1j/2), 1/2, (-1j/2), 0;
     0,    0 ,     0 ,  0,      1.00
          ];

T = A.*1

Tinv = inv(T)
Tinv =

   Inf   Inf   Inf   Inf   Inf
   Inf   Inf   Inf   Inf   Inf
   Inf   Inf   Inf   Inf   Inf
   Inf   Inf   Inf   Inf   Inf
   Inf   Inf   Inf   Inf   Inf
```

So, I tried to multiply `T = A.*I` where `I = eye(5)` then took the inverse Eventhough, I don't get infinity value, I am getting element `2` which is not there in the picture for 3 by 3 matrix case. Here is the result

```
Tinv =

   2.0000                  0                  0                  0                  0          
        0                  0 + 2.0000i        0                  0                  0          
        0                  0             2.0000                  0                  0          
        0                  0                  0                  0 + 2.0000i        0          
        0                  0                  0                  0             1.0000
```

If for 3 by 3 matrix case, I  use `I = eye(3)`, then again I get element 2.

```
Tinv =

   2.0000                  0                  0          
        0                  0 + 2.0000i        0          
        0                  0             1.0000
```

What is the proper method?

**Question :** For general case, for any sized matrix `m by m`, should I multiply using `I = eye(m)` ? Using `I` prevents infinity values, but results in new numbers `2`. I am really confused. Please help

**UPDATE:** Here is the full image where Theta is a vector of 3 unknowns which are Theta1, Theta1* and Theta2  are 3 scalar valued parameters. Theta1 is a complex valued number, so we are representing it into two parts, Theta1 and Theta1* and Theta2 is a real valued number. g is a complex valued function. The expression of the derivative of a complex valued function with respect to Theta evaluates to T^H.  Since, there are 3 unknowns, the matrix T should be of size 3 by 3.

[image: pic new]

Comment: The operation `T = A.*I` completely diagonalizes `T` since all elements off the diagonal of ones are `0` for the identity; it's the wrong `T`.  Now if you were to do `T = A*I`, that'd be fine because it does nothing (since a matrix multiply with `I` is like a scalar multiply with `1`), but it wouldn't fix the singular nature of the constructed `A`.

Comment: Have a look at my edit. Are you actually looking for [**`ctranpose`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranpose.html) instead of `inv`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is slightly different than you think. The symbols (**I**, **0**) in the matrices in the images are *not necessarily scalars* (only for `n = 1`), but they are actually *square matrices*.

**I** is an identity matrix and **0** is a matrix of zeros. if you treat these matrix like that you will get the expected answers:

```
n = 2; % size of the sub-matrices
I = eye(n); % identity matrix
Z = zeros(n); % matrix of zeros
% your T matrix
T = [1/2*I, (1j/2)*I, Z;
    1/2*I, (-1j/2)*I, Z;
    Z,Z,I];
% inverse of T
Tinv1 = inv(T);
% expected result
Tinv2 = [I,I,Z;
    -1j*I,1j*I,Z;
    Z,Z,I];
% max difference between computed and expected
maxDist = max(abs(Tinv1(:) - Tinv2(:)))
```

Comment: I am not sure if the dimension of the matrix T should increase. Could you please look at the update, I have provided more information. Thank you for your reply, it is not clear to me why the dimension must increase and why use `Z`

Comment: Are you sure T is 3×3? And if it is, why do you ask about larger T's?

Comment: Look at the [derivative of vector by vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Vector-by-vector), I think that `size(T)` should be `[3*length(theta) 3*length(theta)]`

Comment: There are two cases, the first is when there are 3 theta's or 3 parameters for which the matrix is 3 by 3. The next case is when there are 5 parameters fro which the matrix `T` is 5 by 5

Comment: The next larger matrix is 6x6, not 5x5. `Z` must be a square matrix the same size as `I`.

Answer (score 1):

First you *should know*, whether you should do

```
T = A.*eye(...)
```

or

```
I = A.*1 %// which actually does nothing
```

These are completely different things. Be sure what you need, then think about the code.

---

The reason why you get all `inf` is because the determinant [**`det`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/det.html) of your matrix is **zero**.

```
det(T) == 0
```

So from the mathematical point of view your result is correct, as building the inverse requires every element of `T` to be divided by `det(T)`. Your matrix cannot be inversed. If it should be possible, the error is in your input matrix, or again in your understanding of the actual underlying problem to solve.

### Edit

After your question update, it feels like you're actually looking for [**`ctranpose`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranpose.html) instead of [**`inv`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inv.html).

Comment: I need to do 3 operations on `T` which would give 3 different matrices. The first is (1) inverse of T, then (2) ctranspose of `T` and last (3) the inverse of the ctranspose of `T`.